# Apache Karaf stuck while shutting with Pax-Exam

Tags: junit, apache-karaf, maven-surefire-plugin, pax-exam

I was running integrations tests with Pax-Exam and Karaf, tests got executed successfully but while shutting Karaf, it stuck on below and never resume

Pax-Exam = 4.11
Karaf = 4.2

```
[main] DEBUG o.ops4j.store.intern.TemporaryStore - Exit store(): 66cf6a516d0d1a670e78bd6b0be97f3da2a380b3
[main] DEBUG o.o.p.e.c.remote.RBCRemoteTarget - Preparing and Installing bundle (from stream )..
[main] DEBUG o.o.p.e.r.c.RemoteBundleContextClient - Packing probe into memory for true RMI. Hopefully things will fill in..
[main] DEBUG o.o.p.e.c.remote.RBCRemoteTarget - Installed bundle (from stream) as ID: 86
[main] DEBUG o.o.p.e.c.remote.RBCRemoteTarget - call [[TestAddress:PaxExam-bc970a6c-c656-4aa6-9300-35ded2bcde50 root:PaxExam-f6737e31-8f28-43e
0-847e-1f3f49649233]]
[main] DEBUG o.o.p.e.k.c.i.KarafTestContainer - Shutting down the test container (Pax Runner)
```

Following is output of JConsole for blocking

```
Name: main
State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@d53a0bb owned by: KarafJavaRunner
Total blocked: 106  Total waited: 105

Stack trace: 
org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.runner.InternalRunner.shutdown(InternalRunner.java:71)
org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.runner.KarafJavaRunner.shutdown(KarafJavaRunner.java:120)
   - locked org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.runner.KarafJavaRunner@279baf5b
org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.KarafTestContainer.stop(KarafTestContainer.java:600)
   - locked org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.KarafTestContainer@25dcfa62
org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactor.invoke(AllConfinedStagedReactor.java:87)
org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner$2.evaluate(ProbeRunner.java:267)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner.run(ProbeRunner.java:98)
org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:93)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Update:
One more thing i observed if i forcefully shut it and then if i run "mvn clean install" i get following error and i have to wait to get it run again

```
[←[1;31mERROR←[m] Failed to execute goal ←[32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean←[m ←[1m(default-clean)←[m on project ←[36mosgi-unit-tes
ts-sample←[m: ←[1;31mFailed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\..\target\pax
exam\e266ddcb-5fed-4997-8178-3d4944251418\system\org\apache\felix\org.apache.felix.framework\5.6.10\org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.10.jar←[m -> ←[1m[Help 1
```

Update2:

After exiting prompt still its running

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin>jps -l
1552 sun.tools.jps.Jps
4144
1420 org.apache.karaf.main.Main

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin>jps -l 1420
RMI Registry not available at 1420:1099
Exception creating connection to: 1420; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

Update3:
if i kill this process, Pax resume and display message successful execution of Tests. infact before shutting all tests are already successfull but it not able to shut.

```
 TASKKILL /F /PID 10692
```

Now i have no clue to handle this locking issue.

Update4:
Name: main
State: WAITING on org.apache.felix.framework.util.ThreadGate@b3d26d8
Total blocked: 6  Total waited: 7

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
org.apache.felix.framework.util.ThreadGate.await(ThreadGate.java:79)
org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.waitForStop(Felix.java:1075)
org.apache.karaf.main.Main.awaitShutdown(Main.java:640)
org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:188)
```

Name: FelixDispatchQueue

```
State: WAITING on java.util.ArrayList@3276dd18
Total blocked: 353  Total waited: 342

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:1122)
org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:54)
org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update5:
After spending lot of time i finally realize that by adding below bundles it got stuck, if i dont add them it works fine

```
wrappedBundle( maven("org.ops4j.pax.tinybundles", "tinybundles").versionAsInProject() ), //2.1.0
wrappedBundle( maven("biz.aQute.bnd", "bndlib").versionAsInProject() )//2.4.0
```

Regards,

Comment: This might be a problem with file locking. Unfortunately these problems typically only show on windows and most karaf devs test on linux or mac.

About the problem after killing karaf. Are you sure the karaf process is really stopped? The issue sounds like felix is still running.

Comment: Yes its still running with RMI Registry error i update with update2 by running jps, Any suggestions for locking issue?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Same behavior on linux and it remain on this "Shutting down the test container (Pax Runner)" forever.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in a small test project that we can look into?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider as i am migrating existing itest and after spending lot of time add/remove different i reachd that by adding below bundles its showing problem. please find in updates

Comment: Why do you use wrappedBundle there ? Both jars should already be bundles. Btw. You can avoid deploying TinyBundles in many cases using a small trick. See https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-testing-example/blob/master/src/test/java/net/lr/example/testing/osgi/tb/BndDSOptions.java

Comment: @ChristianSchneider upgrading org.ops4j.pax.tinybundles to 3.0.0 resolved the problem. Dependency Matrix in documentation would be very valuable. I am unable to find.

Comment: You mean a dependency matrix for tinybundles? You can look it up from the maven pom or even better the bundle Manifest but of course that would not hint to do an upgrade.

I guess one of the dependencies in tinybundles 2 clashed with the main pax exam. For tinybundles 3 I worked on having less dependencies. 
See also   https://ops4j1.jira.com/projects/PAXTB/versions/23801/tab/release-report-all-issues

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I mean to see dependency matrix of pax-exam/karaf as it was previously available on following URL. which is no more accessible. i remember it contain information in tabular form http://karaf.apache.org/index/documentation/karaf-dependencies/karaf-deps-4.0.x.html

Comment: That is not from pax exam. It is from Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved issue by changing following jars version

```
maven("org.ops4j.pax.tinybundles", "tinybundles") from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0
maven("biz.aQute.bnd", "bndlib")                  from 2.4.0 to 3.5.0
```